# Exit_form doesn't work as expected

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using exit_form to close a form. But, when I call that form from another form and then press the exit key, it returns to the form which called it. 
Example: 
if form_a calls form_b. In form_b trigger exit_forms triggers, it will call form_b. 
Well, I need to exit all opened form.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use then new_form statement instead of open_form or call_form:

new_form exits the current form and enters the indicated form. The calling form is terminated as the parent form. If the calling form had been called by a higher form, Oracle Forms keeps the higher call active and treats it as a call to the new form. Oracle Forms releases memory (such as database cursors) that the terminated form was using.Oracle Forms runs the new form with the same Run form options as the parent form. If the parent form was a called form, Oracle Forms runs the new form with the same options as the parent form.NEW_FORM can be instructed to continue the database transaction, rollback to the current save point or perform a full rollback. It can also be instructed to open the new form in query only mode and to share or not share library data.

Answer (score 0):

according to oracle forms help

call_form:
Runs an indicated form while keeping the parent form active. Oracle Forms runs the called form with the same Runform preferences as the parent form. When the called form is exited Oracle Forms processing resumes in the calling form at the point from which you initiated the call to CALL_FORM.

open_form:
Opens the indicated form. Use OPEN_FORM to create multiple-form applications, that is, applications that open more than one form at the same time.

---

so I suggested to try use open_form with no_active parameter then call exit_form to exit form (A), after form(A) closed the focus will gained by opened form(B).
so you finish working on form(B) and close it, it will exit all your forms.

to simplify :
on form_A on button trigger when_pressed_button (which responsible to open form_B) you can try

```
OPEN_FORM('form_b', NO_ACTIVATE, NO_SESSION, 'my_parameters');
exit_form(no_validate);
```